# Overfitting ML model

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, classification

i have a problem with my image classifier, it's shows validation error over 500% and it gives me a training loss of 2% along with training accuracy of 90%+.

I also tried transfer learning using **fastai** and using **resnet50** and it also gives me the same results.

Here is my results:
-validation error: 500%
-validation error: about 2%
-validation accuracy: 90%+
-no of epochs: 50

Hint: my data is a scraped images from Google, i have 10 classes, each class have about 600-700 image.

Thanks for your time

Here is my code guys.

```
from fastai.vision import *
from fastai.metrics import error_rate

path = Path('drive/My Drive/cheese images/')

np.random.seed(42)
data = ImageDataBunch.from_folder(path, train='.', valid_pct = 0.2,
                              ds_tfms = get_transforms(), size = 224, 
num_workers=4).normalize(imagenet_stats)

learn = cnn_learner(data, models.resnet50, metrics = accuracy)

learn.fit_one_cycle(50)
learn.export()
learn.unfreeze()
```

Comment: Can you tell us what data you are using? What are the classes? Maybe some samples of your data and code, what exactly are you doing?

Comment: So you are using a ResNet-50 with (I assume) the cross entropy loss function. Could you please share info about the optimizer (SGD, AdaGrad, Adam...) and the hyperparameters? It's hard to help you without those info. Also, 500% is simply a value you shouldn't get. Never. Probably you are messing up with the error metrics.

Comment: `Your question seems to be inconsistent *training accuracy of 90%+* vs *validation accuracy: 90%+ -* if both are the same it is not overfitting

Comment: Dude 500% error, usually signifies a bug in your code! Not in your model training ^_^

Comment: I have modified my original post, have a look at the code guys ^_^